# Umbraco caching

Tags: caching, macros, umbraco

I'm having real problem with caching in a macro. I've set the cache period to 0 but still a dropdownlist that returns a list of other items in the content tree won't update until I force the application to recycle e.g. touch the web.config file.

The Macro uses umbraco.content.Instance.XmlContent.SelectSingleNode to select a parent node and then loops through the children and adds these to the dropdownlist.

When I add a new child to this node it doesn't appear in the dropdownlist even if I publish the entire website again.

I'm not sure where this caching is taking place. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What version of Umbraco is this with?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **?umbdebug=true** or **?umbdebugshowtrace=true** to any page on your website, it will display trace/macro information.

This video series, maybe helpful
http://umbraco.tv/documentation/videos/for-developers/foundation/macro-caching

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(docId);` before the SelectSingleNode call and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve your caching problem by providing version to a particular file like css, .js or change something into the web.config file whenever you will go for the deployment.

For example : If we have Script.js file then change version of file for Script.js ?123.

When we changed the version of a file then server will get the latest code from that file.

Let me know if you have any further query.

Thanks